# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Ask Ubuntu's [seventh moderator election](https://askubuntu.com/election/7) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Ravexina] [image: Zanna]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://askubuntu.com/election/7), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5145958359760896/0).

Answer (score 23):

#### [OMG](https://giphy.com/gifs/sesamestreet-sesame-street-50th-anniversary-ZbUIi5RuPahtCN90OL/tile)

Many thanks from me to everyone who participated in the election, especially the folks who stepped up to be candidates.

Congratulations to Ravexina!

I will do my best to serve the community <3 <3 <3

Comment: Congrats, it was high time that you became a mod! I am sure that you'd do a great job. AU is lucky to have a moderator of your calibre.

Comment: @BhargavRao *blush* that's so kind of you <3

Comment: Congrats! Great to see you join the mod team.

Comment: Very glad to see you got elected. I've been following your dedicated work on high quality answers here for a long time now (even before becoming a user myself), and still stumble upon many helpful answers, comments and edits you wrote here for problems encountered years ago.

Comment: Congratulations Zanna! Completely agree with @Pizza. Your contributions really help build the community here.

Comment: Congratulations Zanna! glad to see you selected.

Comment: Thank You Zanna :) I wish you best of lucks and I'm sure that community will definitely benefits from your great works.

Comment: Congrats Zanna!!

Comment: Sorry that I'm so late to the party, but congratulations :D I know you'll make a great moderator

Comment: Congrats Zanna!

Answer (score 18):

A lot of thanks to AskUbuntu family...

Congratulations to Zanna :)

Thanks to everyone who participated in the election in any form. We had great opponents in the election. Thanks to all of them.

Thank you for putting your [trust](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijvgn.png) in me.

I'll do as much as it's possible for me to help the community.

Thank you all.

Comment: Congrats Ravexina!!!

Comment: Congrats Ravexina!

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations to the new moderators. Hope the community will get benefited from their works.

Answer (score 1):

Cool, my two favorites became moderators. Congratulations to you two. I'm looking forward to a good year on this forum. Thanks for your efforts! I'm happy

Comment: Not again… This is [_not_ a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/217657).